Is it possible to use a constraint stream collector (or something similar) without groupBy()?
I'm trying to model a constraint based on the sum of a field across all instances of one of my entities, but the collectors work in concert with groupBy().  I don't want the grouping, just the operator over all the instances.  Something like:
constraintFactory
    .forEach(MeaningOfLife.class)
    .sum(MeaningOfLife::getValue) // obviously doesn't work
    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, totalMeaning -> totalMeaning != 42)
    .asConstraint("Meaning of life is always 42");


I may be modeling this incorrectly, i've worked around it for now by using an EasyScoreCalculator, but i'd like to move the logic to the preferred constraint stream approach.

The technically correct answer to the question as phrased is "No."
But actually, it's kind-of a "Yes":
constraintFactory.forEach(MeaningOfLife.class)
    .groupBy(sum(MeaningOfLife::getValue))
    .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, totalMeaning -> totalMeaning != 42)
    .asConstraint("Meaning of life is always 42");

